# Basic property of $o_p$/stochastic orders of magnitude

Tags: limits, probability-theory, asymptotics

I am totally comfortable and can rigorously prove the fact that for any pair of random sequences say $\{X_n, Y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ I have: $X_n o_p(Y_n) = o_p(X_n Y_n)$, and in particular I also have $X_n o_p(1) = o_p(X_n)$. However one of the "basic facts" is that $o_p(X_n) = X_n o_p(1)$, and I am totally stuck on trying to prove this to myself using the definition/first principles.

If anyone could give a rigorous proof of this it would be greatly appreciated.

I think the point at which I get really confused is what it even means for a random sequence sequence $\{Z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ to be in the set of random sequences $X_n o_p(1)$.

Also I was curious as to whether or not this "basic fact" could be extended to the statement $o_p(X_n Y_n) = Y_n o_p(X_n)$ for any two general random sequences.

Comment: $Y_n = X_n o_p(1)$ if and only if $Y_n = X_n Z_n$, where $Z_n \overset{p}{\to} 0$, no?

Comment: Yes, I totally agree and that would be how I would interpret it....but how would you go from: Given $Y_n = o_P(X_n)$, then $Y_n = X_n Z_n$ for some $Z_n = o_p(1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say that $Y_n = o_p(X_n)$ if and only if

$$ \frac{Y_n}{X_n} \overset{p}{\to} 0. $$

This is equivalent to saying that $Y_n = X_nZ_n$ for some $Z_n \overset{p}{\to} 0$. To see this, just define

$$ Z_n = \frac{Y_n}{X_n}.$$

In other words, $Y_n = X_n o_p(1)$. Thus, $o_p (X_n) = X_n o_p (1)$.

Comment: Ah thank you - that totally makes sense!